# Is there a possibility to add label "subject ID number" R-geom_histogram (ID on each bar for all subjects) of variable on x-axis and count on y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I created a histogram with a number (count) of subjects on the y-axis and I'm trying to find a way to add the ID label of each ID on each bar of the histogram. I tried geom_text and geom_text_repel but I still can't get the number to be organized exactly on each bar for each subject.

For my dataset I'm reading a CSV file with 72 subjects, the columns are ID and Drugratio

ggplot code:

```
plot_5 <- ggplot(All_data, aes(x=as.numeric(logMRP), fill = as.factor(PATIENTID)))+geom_histogram(aes( bins = 30, label=as.factor(PATIENTID)))+ geom_text( stat='count', aes(label=ID), color="Black", size=3, check_overlap = TRUE, hjust=1, position=position_stack(vjust=0.5 ))+theme(legend.position = "none")
show(plot_5)
```

Any suggestions!
Thank you[image]

Comment: Please share a little bit of reproducible sample data so that we can have something to work with. And please show the code you are currently using. `dput()` is a great function for making a copy/pasteable version of an R object, for example you could share `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @GregorThomas, I added the code and short description of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your data or code, we can only guess, but it seems your data is something like this:

```r
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(ID = factor(1:72), value = 2 - rgamma(72, 3, 2))
```

And your plotting code is like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(value, fill = ID)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ID, y = ..count..),
            check_overlap = TRUE) +
  guides(fill = guide_none()) +
  labs(x = NULL)
```

[image]

This looks very similar to your own plot. To fix it, let's use `stat_bin` with `position = position_stack()` for the text layer.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = value, fill = ID)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
  stat_bin(geom = "text", bins = 30, na.rm = TRUE,
           aes(label = ifelse(after_stat(count) == 0, NA, after_stat(group)), 
               group = ID, y = after_stat(count)),
           position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = guide_none())  +
  labs(x = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Following the great suggestions I got from Allan Cameron, I was able to add the ID values for each subject similar to the graphs above

```
plot_5_new <- ggplot(All_data, aes(x=as.numeric(logMRP), fill = as.factor(ID)))+geom_histogram(bins=30)+ stat_bin(geom = "text", bins = 30, na.rm = TRUE, aes(label = ifelse(after_stat(count) == 0, NA, after_stat(group)), group = as.factor(ID), y = after_stat(count)),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + guides(fill = guide_none())+theme(legend.position = "none") show(plot_5_new)
```